# Have never vs have not

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

What is the difference between following 2 sentences?

In which situation can we use " I've never" and "I've not"??

1: I've never been there.

2:I've not been there.

Comment: "*I've not been there.*" can be qualified:  "*I've not been there **today***" whereas "*I've never*" cannot.

Answer (score 1):

In that example, I would say they mean the same thing. If you've never been to a certain place, you've also not been there. But if I say 'I've never been good', I'm saying that I've always been bad, but then if I say 'I've not been good', then I've only been bad then, but good other times. So, I guess it depends on the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

More technically, the adverb 'never' expresses a temporal context (i.e. at no time), whereas 'not' is a simple negative clause.

**never** - adverb: at no time in the past or future; not ever.
"they had never been camping in their lives"

**not** - adverb: used with an auxiliary verb or ‘be’ to form the negative.
"he would not say"

Answer (score 0):

Both the examples you provide are natural discourse. Still, I would say "I've never been there" has a slightly less casual tone.  "I've not been there" would be something we might say rather than write. Hope that helps.